# New version of REST API - deploy two services?

Tags: java, rest, api

Assume you need to define a completely new REST API for a given service. These rest APIs are distinguished by something like "v1" and "v2" in the path.

If you develop these services in Java, would you:

1. Add the new access points to the given project and deploy a new version that supports both the v1 and the v2 paths?
2. Remove all the v1 access points from the project, add the new v2 access points and deploy two different versions of your service simultaneously on your server?

Solution 1 has the disadvantage that it is difficult to update library versions because all changes need to be made for both APIs. Solution 2 has the disadvantage that you have two productive versions of the same service which might be confusing. Additionally, fixing bugs means fixing two programs.

Comment: I'm not sure how these things look like in Java environment, but how we used to this is using ASP.NET WebApi2: we install one instance of the API, which serves both v1 and v2. We deploy the v1 using the [Obsolete] attribute to indicate clients that this version will be deprecated in future, and allow them some time (of course it's clearly communicated how much) to use the v2.

Comment: Seems to me that either approach is viable, but decisions like this are typically driven by business needs. Versioning mostly impacts consumers.

Comment: @DanWilson From the outside, both solutions will look the same. Both v1 and v2 are visible. The difference is purely in structure and maintainability.

Comment: "Solution 1 has the disadvantage that it is difficult to update library versions because all changes need to be made for both APIs." Can you clarify? Which kind of libraries are you talking about? In any case, whether you deploy as two different services or a single one does not change much. Since your API layers do not do any business logic and only delegate to the appropriate layer, you wouldn't have to fix bugs twice, and both API layers can be completely independent (though some people sometimes delegate the v1 to the v2 directly, if possible).

Comment: Is v2 an API redesign or a service redesign?? That is, does it still do the same things internally, but with different endpoints?

Comment: @VincentSavard I am talking about Java libraries. You have the conflicting aims of not touching the implementation of v1 too much (you might break things) and updating all Java libraries for v2 (which might require changes in v1 as well).

Comment: @Darkhogg It is an extension and reorganisation of v1. So with v2 you can do more, and existing features got a new structure.

Comment: I believe you may not be asking yourself the right question. From a software architecture point of view, both solutions are identical. In Java, you would have a module such as `your-service` which does the actual job. The module `your-service-api-v1` would depend on `your-service`. The module `your-service-api-v2` would also depend on `your-service`. Those modules are independent: If you need to fix a bug, then only `your-service` changes, unless obviously the bug is at the API layer level, but since both the v1 and v2 modules are independent, you wouldn't have the same bug to fix twice.

Comment: If your system is split into modules correctly, then you can either deploy both APIs as part of the same process, or in different processes. The choice is yours, and probably depends on whether there are incompatible libraries being used between the v1 and v2 modules, or whether you want to scale both APIs different, or whether you can support the memory/CPU overhead of running two web services.

Comment: Note also that you should have a plan to migrate all your clients from v1 to v2 and eventually deprecate and shut down v1 (or stop supporting altogether, at least). If this is a private/internal API, all that should not be too hard.

Comment: @VincentSavard Thank you. In your words, my problem would be that `your-service` also evolves. You might have programmed `your-service-api-v1` against `your-service-1.0` and program `your-service-api-v2` against `your-service-2.0`. Now you can either run two separate programs with different versions of `your-service` (and if you have a bug, write `your-service-1.0.1` and `your-service-2.0.1`) or you can update `your-service-api-v1` to use `your-service-2.0` which takes time and might introduce additional bugs.

Comment: My first instinct is that this would be mistake. You shouldn't have two versions of `your-service`, both APIs should depend the same version. You should think of an API as a dumb layer on top of your actual business logic. If the actual business logic changes, then obviously your API should use the most recent version at all time. I have a feeling that you coupled the v1 too tightly with the business logic, resulting in difficulty to separate a clear, distinct API out of it, and this is leading you to an incorrect architecture when you realised the v1 did not fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big fan of backwards compatibility generally, and managing end of life of a service as a first class concern, so

- By preference: if it is possible to extend the interface without breaking existing clients, then go ahead and do that.
- If it is not possible, then deploy a new service with the new interface, and end of life the old service.

> If you want to break with the past, use a different hostname, with new branding! -- [Fielding 2013](https://www.slideshare.net/evolve_conference/201308-fielding-evolve/35)

So end of life here really means something like advertising that the legacy service has been deprecated, and communicating to consumers when support for the new service ends.

I sometimes think of the contract between service and consumers as a subscription -- when consumers subscribe, they are given a promise that the service will continue to be available until some fixed point in the future, and the understanding that they can renew the subscription.

(Subscription isn't a great term, because we aren't really talking about billing here, so much as a guarantee that the service will be available until *at least* $DATE).

It may help to review Pieter Hintjens: [The End of Software Versions](http://hintjens.com/blog:85).

> The first step to enlightenment is to see that contracts have a life-cycle. This applies to all contracts, both in software and in the real world. The contract life-cycle is not an invention, it's a feature of real world economics, and a useful one for software engineering.

Answer (score 1):

You should deploy a server which supports BOTH v1 and v2, to give time for clients to migrate their API usage (so what you called option 1).

How many old versions you support, and for how long, is a function of your business practices, how quickly you transition between versions, how quickly you transition clients (client software), and the costs of breaking client software due to version skew (a client that counts on v1 breaks because you got rid of support for v1).

A good rule of thumb from my experience (maybe says more about the businesses I worked in - may not apply to yours) - is to maintain backward compatibility for a year or two.

Note also - I always rewrite my API implementation for v1 (once I have v2 available) to simply INDIRECT/CALL the v2 API. This reduces the code duplication and makes it clearer just what the differences are between the versions of the APIs.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Both of OP options behave the same from the outside.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen I edited the response to make it more clear. It is a clear and direct response to his question. He said "should I do a or b" and my answer was "a" and here is why (and a few hints how).